# Graphics are Caused When i am trying to Change Jpanel In Jframe

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

```
public class ExamplePane extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public ExamplePane() {
        // this is constructor 
        initComponents();

    }
    private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel2.invalidate();
    }                                    

    private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        jPanel2.setVisible(true);
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        jPanel1.invalidate();
    }                                    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new ExamplePane().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

when u trying to display one by one jpanel on the click event then panels are overlapping in that. so please help me for this.

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

1. you have to use `CardLayout`, there are only two `JPanel`s, override only `mouseClicked()` (from  MouseEvents) in `MouseAdapter`
2. you doing changes to already visible Swing GUI, is required to notify used `LayoutManage`r that there are changes, use `(re)validate()` and `repaint()` instead of `invalidate();`, then playing  with `setVisible` isn't required too

Comment: but its already configured in Netbeans.. i am using netbeans 7.3.1 so there is no need of using Layoutmanager its automatically configured that.

Comment: *"i am using netbeans 7.3.1 so there is no need of using Layoutmanager"*  <head-desk />  We've just lost another developer to the dark side.  When the darkness scares the crap out of you and reduces you to a quivering mess of nerves, feel free to come back and join us in the light. :)

Comment: ya but i short out that problem with using Absolute LayOut. and ya what you are taking about?? please give straight answer in this Andrew...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class ScrollLabel extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public  ScrollLabel() {

        setSize(400, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(null);
        jPanel1 = new JPanel();
        jPanel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        jPanel1.add(new JLabel("Panel 1"));

        jPanel2 = new JPanel();
        jPanel2.setBackground(Color.green);
        jPanel2.add(new JLabel("Panel 2"));

        jLabel1 = new JLabel("jPanel 1");
        jLabel2 = new JLabel("jPanel 2");

        jPanel1.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight()-50));
        jPanel2.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(),getHeight()-50));
        jLabel1.setBounds(0, getHeight()-40, 100,30);
        jLabel2.setBounds(getWidth()/2, getHeight()-40, 100,30);

        jLabel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        jLabel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));


        add(jPanel1);
        add(jPanel2);
        add(jLabel1);
        add(jLabel2);

        repaint();

        jLabel1.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                jLabel1MouseClicked(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });


        jLabel2.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                jLabel2MouseClicked(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            }
        });

    }

    private void jLabel1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jPanel1.setVisible(true);
        jPanel2.setVisible(false);
        jPanel2.invalidate();
    }

    private void jLabel2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jPanel2.setVisible(true);
        jPanel1.setVisible(false);
        jPanel1.invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new ScrollLabel().setVisible(true);

    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: you have exception in this program  java.awt.HeadlessException